# SMS sending and founds some error . How to Solve This

Tags: php

Sending now SMS and getting error HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed. URl Use LIke

```
        $sms_url="https://www.smsgatewayhub.com/api/mt/SendSMS?APIKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&senderid=xxxxxx&channel=2&DCS=0&flashsms=0&number=91xxxxxxxxxx&text=Hellow There !&route=1";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sms_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $resp = curl_exec($ch);
        $resp =  substr($resp, 0, -1);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error. Are you sure the parameters are right ? as given in the following [example](https://www.nowsms.com/download/sendsms-php.txt)

Comment: Yes All parameters are Right